# What is the difference between "Real Aikido" and traditional aikido?

Tags: aikido, style

"Real Aikido" is a Serbian martial art founded by [Ljubomir Vračarević](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljubomir_Vra%C4%8Darevi%C4%87) originating from traditional aikido. I have been training traditional aikido for 4 years and trained aikido with aikidokas who train "Real Aikido" but didn't see a big difference, at least for techniques we were doing. What is the difference between "Real Aikido" and traditional aikido?

Comment: @Endery I think comparing two styles especially with such woolly criterion as "fight" and "self defence" would be over broad. However, a specific technique (or set of such as oshi taoshi/ikkio/ikkajo for example) would be a good question.

Comment: The name of the style can be misleading.  Perhaps, refer to it as "Real Aikido" - with caps and quotes to distinguish it as a pronoun?  Traditional aikido can be left without quotes and caps to denote something more generic.  On the other hand, there are other styles of Aikido - Aikikai, Yoshinkan, Iwama, Tomiki, for example - and they're distinct from each other.  So  comparison between Real and Aikikai might be different between Real and Yoshinkan, since there are differences between Aikikai and Yoshinkan.

Comment: @Wigwam Tomiki called his style *Shodokan*.

Comment: Oh, I always thought they were different!  I don't know much about the style, there is only one dojo I can find in NJ, they say they are part of the "Tomiki Aikido of the Americas".  What is the difference between an org calling itself Tomiki or Shodokan?  Is it just in name?

Comment: @Wigwam Time to ask a question?… ☺

Answer (score -2):

answer is - RA is NOT Aikido but initially it was Aikido.  Aikido doesnt have homocide techniques, JuJutsu has - RA also has. RA initially didnt have kills, battery and serious injuries. In attempt to create distinct style of Aikido, Vracarevic merely returned principles that Osensei Morihei Ueshiba removed from Jjj. Aikido didnt emerge instantly - by 1942 it was known as Aikibudojutsu, and even today if kicks,punches,etc are involved we use the term "Aikijutsu". If its only tripping, locks,no intensive violence we call it Aikido. RealAikido teaches necklocks, spinalcord dislocations and variety of fist,elbow,knee,foot blows. IMHO - Aikido must never ever teach lethal techniques *Jjj,Bjj,Judo,Sambo and CACC allow learning but bann applying such techniques*.

Comment: Sources would improve this answer.  Tomiki Aikido teaches atemi waza (strikes), including a spinal dislocation, and even advises that 50% of your techniques should be atemi waza; the goshin jutsu kata includes kicks.  Both TOmiki and Yoshinkan aikido include weapons work with sword, staff and knife; I don't know whether those are "homicidal", but they might be.    I'm just not sure that your answer holds up to scrutiny.

Answer (score -2):

Ra lost the concept of harmony as in aikido, harmony is the main thing or main core.. real aikido punches the enemy but aikido doesnt use any punch instead of reflect.

Comment: *Welcome to the site.* Might I strongly suggest you looked at the [help] to see how we work. While this does answer the question, it make bold claims without any justification whatsoever and is therefore a bad answer which will attract down votes. Could you edit it to substantiate your claims?

Comment: Does "Ra" = Real Aikido?